# Python code to convert urls from list to pdf

Tags: python, qt

I have been trying to find a way to convert a list of url's to pdf with Python 2.7, I thought this would be easy but after a few days at it I'm no further on. 
The code below works fine for just one url.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
#web.show()

printer = QPrinter()
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
printer.setOutputFileName("file.pdf")

def convertIt():
    web.print_(printer)
    print "Pdf generated"
    QApplication.exit()

QObject.connect(web, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), convertIt)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So for ease I created a text file of just 3 url's for the list and then ran a loop through the code for each url but this doesn't work. I have tried various ways but cant get the code to run successfully in a loop. I have managed various outputs such as just one complete pdf or 3 different blank pdf's.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

with open ('testurl.txt', 'r') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)

        web = QWebView()
        web.load(QUrl(line))
        #web.show()
        printer = QPrinter()
        printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
        printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        printer.setOutputFileName('one.pdf')

        def convertIt():
            web.print_(printer)
            print "Pdf generated"
            QApplication.exit()

        QObject.connect(web, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), convertIt)
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I leave the sys,exit line in the script terminates after the first pdf is saved if I take it out I get :-

```
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice

Process finished with exit code 1
```

id prefer to use this code if possible as it looks simple enough and I intend using it in a Qt based GUI app if I can get it to work in a loop.
It looks like it should be very simple to make it work in a loop but it isnt for me..

Answer (score 1):

Usually, there's only a single `QApplication` during the lifetime of the program, instead of creating and destroying them. For this job, the same can be applied to the WebView and the printer, the latter just needing to update the output filename between print calls.

Below is a sample version that loads the filenames into a list and starts scheduling loads inside `QTimer` single shots and waiting for the load finished signal to print and scheduling again. Only when the list is empty the `finished()` signal is emitted.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

class PdfConverter(QObject):

    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.web = QWebView()
        self.printer = QPrinter()
        self.printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
        self.printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
        self.urls = []
        self.idx = -1
        QObject.connect(self.web, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), self.convertIt)

    def load_stuff(self):
        with open('testurl.txt', 'r') as f1:
            self.urls = list(enumerate(f1.readlines()))
        self.schedule_job()

    def schedule_job(self):
        if not self.urls:
            self.finished.emit()
            return

        self.idx, self.newurl = self.urls.pop(0)
        self.newurl = self.newurl.strip()
        print "Loading %s" % self.newurl
        self.web.load(QUrl(self.newurl))

    def convertIt(self, ok):
        if not ok:
            print "Failed to load %s" % self.newurl
        else:
            print "Converting %s" % self.newurl
            self.printer.setOutputFileName("%d.pdf" % self.idx)
            self.web.print_(self.printer)

        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.schedule_job)

def bye():
    QApplication.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    converter = PdfConverter()
    QTimer.singleShot(0, converter.load_stuff)
    converter.finished.connect(bye)
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I'm a novice at Python so forgive me if I'm wrong but it seems to me that you have the same problem as I had,  just moved it somewhere else ...its the same issue as with the 'sys.exit',  your code seems to work fine but it isn't usable as I cant import it as a module, if I try to import it your code runs as soon as its imported (prior to the texturl,txt file being created) due to the missing 'if __name__ == "__main__":'. When I add the 'if __name__' it doesn't run at all. And for the same reasons as above I cant incorporate it into a pyqt4 GUI script.

Comment: Oh, it's not working because I handled it like a single script, sorry, but apart the if/main thing you noticed, the other change is kinda straightforward. You could emit, let's say, a "finished" signal instead of call `QApplication.exit` when there are no more jobs to be scheduled.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, It does what I asked but has not it seems solved my problem entirely.